# Can a single point be considered a function?

Tags: functions, relations

A relation is defined as a set of ordered pairs. A set can include a single point. A function is a relation. Does that mean a single point can be considered a function? Say you have the point (1,0). There is a unique output for the input, but does there need to be multiple inputs and multiple outputs?

Comment: I just want to tweak your terminology a bit.  A set can include a single element.  A single ordered pair can be considered a function.  This includes the ordered pair $(1, 0)$, which maps the element $1$ to the element $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\{(1,0)\}$ is a function. For that matter, $\emptyset$ is a function. A function can have a domain of any size, including $1$ and $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since ∅ is a function, that means it's a relation as well, correct? Or does a relation have to be between multiple sets?

Comment: @NiehlsIngram Yes, the empty function is also the empty relation.

Comment: Great, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my view, any point can be considered function. Specifically, any function with a single answer and a single element may be a function.
For example, {{1},{0}} can be Considered a function if the answer for f{1}~ {0} and the set contains the single element. Thank you for the cooperation.
A function can also have a single element.